# WebForm MVP one view to display different controls after each button click

Tags: asp.net, webforms, mvp

Background:
We are trying to design a page which handles the process of 5 different steps. They follow a linear pattern. But may also need to go back through the steps.

Step 1 > Step 2 > Step 3 > Step 4 > Step 5

Each step has a buttonClick event to initiate the next step.

We are using VB.net.

We have set up our Model View and Presenters along with Model and View interfaces.

What is happening:

We have our control (ascx) for each step which contains the html to display, the backend code contains the btn_click event which amongst some other events passes the the path of the next control to the presenter.

The view contains a placeholder panel which should update with the next control.

Currently the button is clicked and this starts a reload of the view which then does the page_load. According to the page life cycle the button click event should occur before the page is rendered.

We managed to get it working for Step 1 > Step 2 however it just reloads Step 1 again as it never reaches the button event for Step 2. It seems to skip over it. Thus the control for Step 3 onwards is never loaded.

It works for step 1 > step 2 because we load that as the default in the view.

Aim:

The aim is to have the button click fire off and pass the path for the next control. That value should then be passed to the view to load in and replace the previous control.

Is it possible to do this? To load different controls into one view based on click events? To be clear there should only be one control loaded on the page at any time.

I haven't provided any snippets of the code yet as I want to see if this is possible first. From the information I have read it seems to give mixed opinions and there is not a clear answer. I have added a (rough) class diagram to demonstrate the set up we have.

[Class Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XtGma.png)

Comment: Why on earth are you using WebForms in 2021?!

Comment: ASP.NET WebForms is not an MVP framework - nor is it stateful (despite appearances) - please explain how you are managing the lifetime of your Presenter class. Also, why are you trying to shoehorn the MVP pattern into an MVP-unfriendly environment?

Comment: "I haven't provided any snippets of the code yet as I want to see if this is possible first." - yes, it's possible to accomplish this, but with **a lot** of hair-pulling and stress from fighting the (horrible) WebForms system. The easiest way (using WebForms) is to stop trying to build your own MVP system and use `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Wizard` instead - which provides **exactly** what you're after, but the **best way** would be to  join us 16 years in the future in 2021 and ditch WebForms entirely.

Comment: Unfortunately we are stuck using web forms as we are maintaining an older legacy system. We were undergoing a refactor of the project and as an off-shoot were trying new approaches to see what can and can't be done and whether or not this is viable. I share the same sentiment that this should be overhauled completely but is not in my power to do so. 

We partially got some version of it working using viewstate.

Comment: Is there any reason you can't use (the original) ASP.NET MVC within the project? It co-exists with WebForms in the same Web Application project. You just need to fiddle with setting up routing, but then everything gets significantly easier.

Comment: Thanks for the information, this has been a good learning exercise for us so we will go back and see what we can do. (All whilst aggressively suggesting the business ditch webforms...)

Comment: I think the reason was the person leading the project had already done some refactoring elsewhere (along with others) who have used the MVP approach. Hence why we started with MVP.